# Composition of linear mapping and fixed point.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, linear-transformations, fixed-points

*Question:*
$E= \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and $E$ is a normed vector space$(E; ||.||)$. Let $a$ be a linear continuous mapping and we writte $a^p = a \circ  a \circ ... \circ a$ $p$ times (with $"\circ"$ [composition law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)). Moreover, we define $$b_p=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}a^k}{p}$$
Let a point $x \in E$ s.t. the sequence $\left \{ a^p(x) \right \} $ is bounded. Show that every point in $E$ that is a possible sub-sequential limit of the sequence $\left \{ b_p(x) \right \}$ is a fixed point of the linear mapping $a$.

*My best attempt: see a more details answer in the answer*
My best attempt until now it the one below (just take it as a try and any feedback will be great).
First of all note that $a \circ b_p(x)=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{p}a^k}{p}=b_p \circ a(x)$.
Now let note $b_{p_k}(x)$ a sub sequence with limit $l$, hence we have
(i) $a \circ b_{p_k}(x)\underset{k \to \infty}{\rightarrow} a(l) $
(ii) $b_{p_k} \circ a(x)\underset{k \to \infty}{\rightarrow} l \circ a(x)$
But as (i)=(ii) and because $l \circ a(x) = l$ we have that $a(l)=l$
In all the case I don't fell enough good with this answer (not rigorous enough...)

Moreover, I have tried different ways to solve this question, but I am really stuck any help will be great. Thank you.

Comment: up anyone to help me please?

Comment: up is there someone that can check y sol? thk

Comment: What is $l \circ a(x)$? If I understand your notation $l$ is just some vector in $E$.

Comment: @ronno This was my attempt when I wrotte the question please read my answer for a more details explanation.

Comment: It would still be useful to know what you meant. FYI, you can [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i didn't get yet any help bellow my best answer for the moment.

First of all let [remember](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Metric_spaces) that in any metric space we have that for any continuous function $f$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty } x_n $ exists then $\lim_{n \to \infty } f(x_n ) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty } x_n)$.

Now let take $l$ a sub sequence limit of $\left \{ b_p(x) \right \}$, hence we have $\lim_{k \to \infty }b_{p_k}(x)=l$ and as obvisouly $b_p(x)$ is a continuous fuction (as a finit sum of linear continuous mapping) we get that: $\lim_{k \to \infty }a [b_{p_k}(x)]=a[\lim_{k \to \infty }b_{p_k}(x)]=a(l)$.

On a other side, we can writte $ b_{pk} \circ a = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{p_k}a^i}{p_k}=\frac{p_{k+1}}{p_k}b_{pk+1}-\frac{1}{p_k}Id $. Now if $p_k \to \infty$ by limit arithmetic and by the unicity of the limit of the sub sequence we get that: $\lim_{k \to \infty}{b_{pk} \circ a} = l$.

As we know that $a \circ b_{p} = b_{p} \circ a$ (easy to prove it as it is only continuous linear mapping), hence by applying the limit on the considering sub sequence with limit $l$ we get: $a(l)=l$.

I will be happy to know if it is correct and to read your advices.

EDIT: I get a feed back and it is correct

Comment: up is anyone can check my sol and help me improve it?

Comment: As I didn't get yet any feedback i marked this answer as correct. I will be yet very happy to read comment.

Comment: Uniqueness of limit doesn't apply because you get a different (sub)sequence which a priori may have a different limit.

Comment: You re right I should have precise uniqueness of limit for the subsequence.